# Django - How to add multiple instances of the same model in a field

Tags: python, django

I have a class that looks like this. In the pack items I want to have the number of that instance of Item and how many of that as a number.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    is_pack = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pack_items = models.ManyToManyField(PackItem, blank=True)
```

```
class PackItem(models.Model):
    packitem = models.ForeignKey('Item', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

This seems to work but every time I create a new pack in the admin, I have to create first, one by one, each PackItem and then put them in the packitems field of Item.
The goal is: I have bottles of drinks as Items and I want to have pre-made Packs of these drinks. Would my way of doing it cause problems later on? Is there a better practice? Or is this already wrong?

Comment: Why do you have both a m2m between `Item` and `PackItem`, and a foreign key fom `PackItem` to `Item`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, what you need is a many-to-many field with a [**`through=…`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through). So we can implement a

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)

class Pack(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through='PackItem')

class PackItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pack = models.ForeignKey(Pack, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Here we thus specify that a `Pack` consists out of a collection of items, but the [*junction table* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) will contain an extra parameter named `quantity` that specifies how many times we add the `Item` to the `Pack` object.

Comment: My actual Item model is a lot fatter and I wanted to consider a pack as an Item as well. The only difference between an Item and a pack is that a pack consists of other items. 

`class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    items = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='PackItem')

class PackItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)`

Would something like this do the job?

Comment: @moddayjob: the `ManyToMany` from `Item` to `PackItem` is very "strange", especially since you put a `ForeignKey` from `PackItem` to `Item`. It is not impossible to have multiple relations between two models, but it is not that comon. Furthermore it is very strange that you add a `quantity` to a `PackItem`, since it looks like that is not a property of a `PackItem`, but of how an `Item` relates to a `PackItem`.

Comment: @moddayjob: furthermore I do not really get why you store `is_pack` in the `Item`. Especially since we can determine that by looking if it is a member of a related `Pack`/`PackItem`.

Comment: I might be doing it all wrong. I though considering `Pack` and `Item` as the same thing with a single difference pack contains multiple instances of itself with different quantities. I thought it would be simpler like that.
I thought `is_pack` was handy, but i'll get rid of it.

Comment: @moddayjob: can a pack contain other packs?

Answer (score 0):

This example is an excellent one that helps answer what a through model is.

To further clear things as I needed an extra hour or so of tutorials to understand this:

1- The Item model should be easily understood

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    # Display below in admin 
    def __str__(self): 
       return f"{self.name}"
```

2- The Pack model is the model you create instances in.

```
class Pack(models.Model):
    pack = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="packname")
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through='PackItem')
    # Display below in admin 
    def __str__(self): 
       return f"{self.id}"
```

3- The "PackInfo" model is the intermediary model. You don't manually create any instances here as it does so automatically. What's important is that you add 2 foreignkey fields; one for each model you wish to connect and then whatever additional fields you need (like 'quantity'). The purpose of this example is to add the 'quantity' field.

```
class PackInfo(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pack = models.ForeignKey(Pack, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    # Display below in admin 
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}"
```

The Pack model in the admin should now look like the below (I just added an extra foreignkey field in the Pack model that allows you to select an item):
[image]

Notice how although the Pack model only has 2 fields ('pack' and 'items'), there is an additional field called 'quantity'. This in my humble opinion is the main advantage of using a through model.

Finally, I was able to display the admin as shown in the image using "admin.TabularInline". You set the intermediary model (PackInfo) as a TabularInline admin view. You can then display it as such in the model with the M2M field (Pack). The `extra = 0` is so that no extra empty instances are added in the admin until you press "Add another Pack Info".

```
@admin.register(Item)
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'price')

class PackInfoInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PackInfo
    extra = 0       # Default extra instances to add is 3

@admin.register(Pack)
class PackAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PackInfoInline]
    class Meta:
        model = Pack
```

Comment: I recommend you change the intermediary name from PackInfo to PackItem once you understand the concept as it looks better that way in the admin and would make more sense for your website's users.